# NSDictionary misteries

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

I used many time:

```
NSMutableDictionary* temp   = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[temp setDictionary:[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [currentEvent objectForKey:@"title"],@"titolo",
                                            [currentEvent objectForKey:@"testo"],@"testo",
                                            [currentEvent objectForKey:@"start"],@"date",
                                            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",lastId],@"att_id",
                                            [currentEvent objectForKey:@"pr_id"],@"pr_id",
                                            nil]];
            NSLog(@"%@",temp);
```

but this time, the log prints out:

```
2013-11-22 14:39:08.152 MyApp[93198:70b] {
    titolo = asdasda;
}
```

Why it is just getting one object?
In the debugger I can see that currentEvent has all kesy/objest set...

Answer (score 5):

The method call

```
initWithObjectsAndKeys
```

is nil terminated.
If [currentEvent objectForKey:@"testo"] is nil, the dictionary will ignore all the objects you passed after it.

Comment: I did know that! Is that documented?

Comment: if you look at the header file, it says - (instancetype)initWithObjectsAndKeys:(id)firstObject, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

Comment: I knew the nil termination, but not that if an object is nil, the others are neglected.

Comment: This is the link to the apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdictionary_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/initWithObjectsAndKeys: